# Maven to override ALL repositories

Tags: maven, artifactory

I configured my pom to override central repository, and snapshot.
However, some dependencies have their own pom settings with their own repositories, and those tend to access the web.

For example, grizzly sets glassfish repository. ActiveMQ sets jboss and others.

Can I set something like - override ALL repositories to go to my own repository?

Answer (score 1):

You should setup a [repository manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) afterwards you can configure the access via the settings.xml file to use only the repository manager. This is a kind of override via the [mirror setting in the settings.xml file](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html).

Comment: Thanks. I already setup artifactory. In order to avoid having to distribute settings.xml to all developers machines, how do I set the "morrorOf" in the parent pom?

Comment: You can't define the mirror configuration in the POMs. That's only possible in the `settings.xml` file.

Comment: Anyway, you shouldn't define your repositories within your pom; it goes behind the back of your settings.xml

Comment: I understand that technically I can't. It's too bad, since in some cases I don't have settings.xml, nor would I like to distribute settings.xml to all machines.

Comment: Eiether you have the settings.xml file in the maven installation (conf folder) or you can simply deliver it with your current checkout.